# Solve for $x$: $\;\;\;(1/9)^x=-9$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analysis, logarithms, exponential-function

> Solve for $x$: $\;\;\;(1/9)^x=-9.$

What I tried:

$$(1/9)^x = -9,$$

$$x\log(1/9) = \log(-9).$$

When graphing, I get $x = -1$. However, logarithms of negative numbers are undefined.

Also, $(1/9)^{-1} = 9$, not $-9$. Is this problem undefined, or is the answer $-1$?

Thanks for the help all. The answer seems to be that it is undefined.

Comment: "*When graphing, I get x = -1*" $\;-\;$ You must be graphing wrong. An exponential $a^x$ with $a \gt 0$ can never take negative values.

Comment: Was this problem posed to you, or did you think it up yourself? If the former, the one posing the question probably made a mistake. If you were just wondering, your curiosity is to be commended, but you have stepped into a mathematical sinkhole.

Comment: Someone asked me to help them with this problem, which is from a precalc textbook, and I was unable to solve it. The best answer I could think of was that it is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Try graphing $y=(1/9)^x$. Can you find a value for $x$ that achieves $y=-9$?

Comment: Yes, I found that when x=-1, y=9. However, I am having trouble solving this without a graph.

Comment: You want to look for $y=-9$, not $y=9$ unless there is a typo in the question.

Comment: Oh, you're right. The negative slipped my mind there. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The left side of your equation is always a positive number for any $x$, and the right side is always a negative number. The equation has no solution.

Answer (score 1):

How about we try solving this equation with complex numbers instead of real numbers? Here goes...

$$\begin{align}9^{-x}&=-9\\-x\ln 9&=\ln(-9)\\-x\ln 9&=\ln(-1)+\ln 9\\-x\ln 9&=i\pi+\ln 9\\x&=-1-\dfrac{i\pi}{\ln9}\\\end{align}$$

which is exactly what we get if we type this equation to solve with Maple. So, this is another way of proving that there are no real solutions.